# Where do we define and keep track of the scope of the site

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, scope

I recently voted to close [What is known about minimal sets of axioms?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/801/what-is-known-about-minimal-sets-of-axioms), because I think it would be better suited for (say) [maths.SE](https://maths.stackexchange.com).

The close vote options are:

- This question does not appear to be about Proof Assistants, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help)
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
- Other - add a comment

However,

- the help center says nothing specific about what would be on or off topic specific to proof assistants (to be fair I didn't read everything, so maybe I missed something)

- the second option only suggests PA.meta.SE
- a comment to that effect already existed

So my question is:

- Where do we keep track of what is on and off topic for this site?
- Could we add some or all of math.SE, mathoverflow, CS.SE, Cstheory.SE, and stackoverflow as alternatives for "another site in the Stack Exchange network"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where do we keep track of what is on and off topic for this site?

When the site gets fully shaped (that is, we've decided on which kind of questions are on-topic and welcome), we can edit [how-to-ask](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help pages. (Check out Code Review's [how to ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for comparison.) I believe site moderators get the privilege to do that. Until then, we'll need to wait for some more kinds of questions to come, and decide on individual kinds of questions by discussing it here on meta.

> Could we add some or all of math.SE, mathoverflow, CS.SE, Cstheory.SE, and stackoverflow as alternatives for "another site in the Stack Exchange network"?

To my knowledge, the list of sites that appear on the list are [actual migration paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79960/419414), and SE is very conservative to adding more migration paths. In most cases, it suffices to choose a custom close reason (`Community-specific reason -> Other`) and write "I think this question belongs to [some other site]".

If you really think it is a genuinely good question (on-topic, well-specified and not a duplicate) on the destination site, you can raise a flag for "moderator attention" and make a migration request. Moderators have the ability to migrate questions to any other site, so they will migrate it if they think it is appropriate to do so.